How to DISTINCT column value based on other column value

I have below table information 



Batch_ID
Items
Time
User




Batch_1
50
0.70
Abc


Batch_2
40
0.70
Abc


Batch_2
60
0.70
Abc



I want SQL code where I can calculate the SUM of Items and the SUM of Time but I want to DISTINCT the time value of the same Batch_ID.

The result that I should get is 150 for Items and 1.40 for time.
The results I got for the time value is 0.70.


Below example for the results I want to show: 



User
Sum(Items)
Sum(Time)




Abc
150
1.40



SELECT user_id, SUM(items), SUM(DISTINCT time) FROM items_p GROUP BY dayweek,user_id


Why should you get 1.40 if you only want the distinct time values? Since there are two 1.70 time values for Batch_2, only the one is used and thus the result is 1.70. Could you clarify why this is not the result that you are looking for?

Please post the output you're expecting

@DMalan I want to sum the results for both batch 1 and 2 but to ignore the duplicate time value for the same batch id

I'm not sure if I understand correct, but maybe something like this? https://dbfiddle.uk/gppAaZd_

I hope this will help ^^
SELECT [user] as 'User',SUM(items) as 'Sum(Items)',SUM(TIME) as 'Sum(Time)'
FROM (
    SELECT [user],SUM(items) AS items,SUM(DISTINCT time) AS TIME
    FROM your_table_name
    GROUP BY [user] ,batch_id
    ) AS t1
GROUP BY [user]



Here is the query,
res1 query takes the distinct TIME from table grouped by batch_id,user and then returns both batch_id and user
res2 query takes sum of items grouped by user and then returns both user and sum of items.
Finally do a inner join for both using user.
SELECT res2.t_items,
       SUM(t_times) AS t_times,
       res1.USER
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT TIME AS t_times,
                        USER,
                        batch_id
        FROM   batchdata
        GROUP  BY USER,
                  batch_id
        ORDER  BY t_times DESC) AS res1
       inner join (SELECT USER,
                          SUM(items) AS t_items
                   FROM   batchdata
                   GROUP  BY USER) AS res2
               ON res2.USER == res1.USER 


Thank you very much this code works well I will give it Vote Up but I will choose the other answer since it less complicated and gives same results.
